# Get Element with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, express, puppeteer

I'm having a rather delicate problem with puppeteer right now.

I have the following structure in HTML:

```
<tbody>
   <tr rel="0" class="disabled"              id="user6335934"
      class="odd">
      <!-- row tools -->
      <td style="width: 102px; height: 18px;">
         <a id="edit6335934" class="load_link link fancybox iframe help"
            title="Modifier"
            width="480"
            height="310"
            href="/fr/sphere/98844/utilisateurs/6335934/editer">
         <img alt="Modifier" src="/sfDoctrinePlugin/images/edit.png">
         </a>
         <a id="stats6335934" class="load_link link help"
            title="Consulter les statistiques"
            href="/fr/sphere/98844/utilisateurs/6335934/statistiques">
         <img alt="Consulter les statistiques"
            src="/sfDoctrinePlugin/images/default.png">
         </a>
         <!-- download fiche d'apprentisage -->
         <a class="link help fiche" title="Télécharger le rapport d'apprentissage"
            href="/services-pjv/rest/manager/user/6335934/rapportApprentissage.pdf?applicationId=1">
         <img alt="Télécharger le rapport d'apprentissage" src="/images/telecharger-fiche.png">
         </a>
         <!-- !$progdashEnabled -->
         <a id="reset6335934" class="link help reset"
            title="Relancer la dernière évaluation"
            href="/fr/sphere/98844/utilisateurs/6335934/reinit/eval"
            rel="Max Barbet">
         <img alt="Relancer la dernière évaluation" src="/images/reset.png">
         </a>
      </td>
      <!-- user checkbox -->
      <td>
         <input id="user_check_6335934" class="user_check" name="user_check" type="checkbox" value="6335934" />
      </td>
      <td>
         <p class="ovh nom_groupe" style="max-width: 250px;"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <p class="ovh nom_membre" style="max-width: 250px;">Barbet</p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <p class="ovh prenom_membre" style="max-width: 250px;">Max</p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <p class="ovh pseudo_membre" style="max-width: 300px;">max.barbet@rubrash.com#test</p>
      </td>
      <!-- Dernière Utilisation -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh last_usage" >
            11/08/2020 09:49:36                    
         </p>
      </td>
      <!-- Tps Total Passé -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh total_time_spent">
            11min 4s                    
         </p>
      </td>
      <!-- Evaluation Initiale (note) + Tps évaluation initiale -->
      <!-- Evaluation Initiale (note) -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh initial_evaluation_score" style="">
            <span class='green'>59% -  A1</span>                        
         </p>
      </td>
      <!-- Tps évaluation initiale -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh initial_evaluation_time">
            11min 4s                      
         </p>
      </td>
      <!-- Niveau initiale -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh first_level" >
            <span class='green'>59%</span>                    
         </p>
      </td>
      <!--
         ###########################
         Start Evaluations Data
         ###########################
         -->
      <!--
         ###########################
         
         End Evaluations Data
         
         ###########################
         -->
      <!-- Tps d'entrainement -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh learning_time"
            >
         </p>
      </td>
      <!-- Niveau Atteint -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh reached_level" >
            59%                  
         </p>
      </td>
      <!-- !progdashEnabled -->
   </tr>
   <tr rel="1" class="disabled"              id="user6334857"
      class="even">
      <!-- row tools -->
      <td style="width: 102px; height: 18px;">
         <a id="edit6334857" class="load_link link fancybox iframe help"
            title="Modifier"
            width="480"
            height="310"
            href="/fr/sphere/98844/utilisateurs/6334857/editer">
         <img alt="Modifier" src="/sfDoctrinePlugin/images/edit.png">
         </a>
         <a id="stats6334857" class="load_link link help"
            title="Consulter les statistiques"
            href="/fr/sphere/98844/utilisateurs/6334857/statistiques">
         <img alt="Consulter les statistiques"
            src="/sfDoctrinePlugin/images/default.png">
         </a>
         <!-- download fiche d'apprentisage -->
         <a class="link help fiche" title="Télécharger le rapport d'apprentissage"
            href="/services-pjv/rest/manager/user/6334857/rapportApprentissage.pdf?applicationId=1">
         <img alt="Télécharger le rapport d'apprentissage" src="/images/telecharger-fiche.png">
         </a>
         <!-- !$progdashEnabled -->
      </td>
      <!-- user checkbox -->
      <td>
         <input id="user_check_6334857" class="user_check" name="user_check" type="checkbox" value="6334857" />
      </td>
      <td>
         <p class="ovh nom_groupe" style="max-width: 250px;"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <p class="ovh nom_membre" style="max-width: 250px;">benardd</p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <p class="ovh prenom_membre" style="max-width: 250px;">hugo</p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <p class="ovh pseudo_membre" style="max-width: 300px;">hugo.benard@rubrash.com#test</p>
      </td>
      <!-- Dernière Utilisation -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh last_usage" >
         </p>
      </td>
      <!-- Tps Total Passé -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh total_time_spent">
         </p>
      </td>
      <!-- Evaluation Initiale (note) + Tps évaluation initiale -->
      <!-- need blanks in the case of users with no eval -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh initial_evaluation_score">
            <!-- blank: Evaluation Initiale -->
         </p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <p class="ovh initial_evaluation_time">
            <!-- blank: Tps évaluation initiale -->
         </p>
      </td>
      <!-- Niveau initiale -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh first_level" >
         </p>
      </td>
      <!--
         ###########################
         Start Evaluations Data
         ###########################
         -->
      <!--
         ###########################
         
         End Evaluations Data
         
         ###########################
         -->
      <!-- Tps d'entrainement -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh learning_time"
            >
         </p>
      </td>
      <!-- Niveau Atteint -->
      <td>
         <p class="ovh reached_level" >
            &nbsp;                  
         </p>
      </td>
      <!-- !progdashEnabled -->
   </tr>
```

With puppeteer, I get an email (req.query.email). I would like to retrieve the span content of the "ovh first_level" class corresponding to the retrieved email.

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    const EMAIL_SELECTOR = '#signin_username';
    const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#signin_password';
    const SUBMIT_SELECTOR = '.linkContent';
    const LOGIN_URL = 'url';

    (async () => {
        // set some options (set headless to false so we can see 
        // this automated browsing experience)
        let launchOptions = { headless: false, 
                              args: ['--start-maximized',] // this is where we set the proxy
                            };
    
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
        const page = await browser.newPage();
    
        // set viewport and user agent (just in case for nice viewing)
        await page.setViewport({width: 1366, height: 768});
        await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36');
    
        // go to whatismycountry.com to see if proxy works (based on geography location)
        await page.goto(LOGIN_URL, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })
        await page.click(EMAIL_SELECTOR)
        await page.keyboard.type('login');
        await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
        await page.keyboard.type('password');
        await page.click(SUBMIT_SELECTOR);
        await page.waitForNavigation({
            waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
          });
        const title = await page.evaluate(() => {
            document.querySelector(".pseudo_membre").innerText
          })
               
    
    res.json({
    mail : req.query.mail,
    result : title
    });
    
    })();
})
```

I don't really know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you've got

- Some API, probably created with Express
- It that receives a request with an email
- It needs to find that email on the target site and get some data about user

```
const percent = page.evaluate((email) => {
  // Find element with the given email
  const userElem = [...document.querySelectorAll('.pseudo_membre')].find(
    (user) => user.innerText.includes(email)
  );
  
  // Bail if not found
  if(!userElem) {
    return false;
  }
  
  // Get the table the row in which the email was found
  // and then inside of that find the needed info by the selector
  userElem.closest('tr').querySelector('.ovh.first_level span').innerText
  
}, email); // <-- pass email into page.evaulate
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want:

```
let value = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.ovh.first_level span').innerText)
```